# What is wrong in the for loop I use to create a file source=dest list?

Tags: bash

I try to loop over the file I `find`in a relative path to build a list of `relative path/soure file name=source file name`

```
SHARED_LIB_PACK=""
for LIB in $(find ../level1/leve2/ -name "*.so*")
do
  $SHARED_LIB_PACK=$SHARED_LIB_PACK" "$LIB"="${LIB##*/}
done
```

but as I run it, it complain :

```
 line 6: = ../level1/level2/file.so.1.0=file.so.1.0: No such file or directory
```

Any help will be welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, variable assignment is done via:

```
FOO="bar"
```

and **not**

```
$FOO="bar"
```

The former **will not work**.

Secondly, your quotes seem to be in strange places:

```
SHARED_LIB_PACK=$SHARED_LIB_PACK" "$LIB"="${LIB##*/}
```

should probably be

```
LIB="${LIB##*/}"
SHARED_LIB_PACK="$SHARED_LIB_PACK $LIB"
```

or

```
SHARED_LIB_PACK="$SHARED_LIB_PACK ${LIB##*/}"
```

Comment: Thank you, based on your answer I finalized my script because you catched all the error I made... Once again thank a lot!